# Is it possible to tell whether a given point is a global minimum for a biconvex function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a continuous but non-differentiable function defined with a pointwise maximum,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:79}
f(\vec{x},\vec{y})=\max\{f_{i}(\vec{x},\vec{y})\}_{i=1}^{n}\quad \vec{x}\in X, \vec{y}\in Y,
\end{equation}
where $X$ and $Y$ are convex polygons, and each $f_{i}(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ is bilinear, which makes $f(\vec{ x },\vec{ y })$ biconvex. I.e., for any fixed $\vec{x}_{0}\in X$ and $\vec{y}_{0}\in Y$, $f(\vec{x}_{0},\vec{y})$ and $f(\vec{x},\vec{y}_{0})$ are both convex. My goal is to find at least one global minimum of $f(\vec{ x },\vec{ y })$ analytically, as a function of certain parameters. I have an educated guess about this minimum from minimizing $f(\vec{ x },\vec{ y })$ numerically with some particular values of the parameters. Do I have any way to decide rigorously whether some particular point, $(\vec{ x }^{\star},\vec{ y }^{\star})$, is a global minimum or not?

Using the biconvexity of $ f $, it is relatively easy to show that $f(\vec{ x }^{\star},\vec{ y }^{\star})\le f(\vec{ x }^{\star},\vec{ y }) \forall \vec{ y }\in Y$ and $f(\vec{ x }^{\star},\vec{ y }^{\star})\le f(\vec{ x },\vec{ y }^\star) \forall \vec{ x }\in X$, but going further than this seems hard. Unfortunately, $ f $ is non-differentiable, so all the Lagrange multiplicator based methods are unfeasible.
Since $f_{i}$ is bilinear, and its domain is the product of two convex sets, the global minima of each $f_{i}$ have to be in the extreme points of $X\times Y$. Since $f_{i}$ have no global minima in the inside of $X\times Y$, the global minima of $f$ must be either at some of the extreme points, or at some of the points where $f$ is non-differentiable. This means that for each $f_{i}$, I "only" have to compare $f(\vec{x}^{\star}, \vec{y}^{\star})$ with the value of $f_{i}$ at the extreme points, and at the border of the set  $\{( \vec{x},\vec{y} ): f_{i}(\vec{x},\vec{y})\ge f_{j}(\vec{x}, \vec{y})\quad \forall j = 1 \ldots n\}$, but this is still way too complicated to just bruteforce.

Any suggestion for a way to approach this problem would be appreciated. I only have a rudimentary knowledge of biconvex optimization.